# How to include simple xmlrpc_client library in my simple php project

Tags: php, xml-rpc, xmlrpcclient

I have a simple PHP project which has `xmlrpc.php`-file in php language library.

When I execute a file with `new xmlrpc_client($this->auth_service_url);` it shows

> Class 'xmlrpc_client' not found

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
new \xmlrpc_client($this->auth_service_url);
Or this
 new /xmlrpc_client($this->auth_service_url);

Answer (score 0):

If you are using odoo version 8 then you just follow the below documentation

[Odoo 8 Web service API](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/api_integration.html)

I hope it will helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that xmlrpc_client is not installed in your php configuration properly or is not available in the scope you are running your command. Try creating / checking your php.ini or create an info.php file and see what libraries are loaded for xmlrpc. If you have this xmlrpc file in your project directory you could also make sure you are including it in your php script. In my php scripts I do this.

```
<?php
include "libs/odoorpc.php";
include("libs/xmlrpcs.inc");
```

Where odoorpc is my odoo xmlrpc class for php. And xmlrpcs is a generic xmlrpc library available for php. You will have to replace with the appropriate file names for your circumstance.